# send mail with Django using EmailMessage class

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to send an email using the EmailMessage class provided by Django. My code in views.py is as follows:

```
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'My_message ', 'my@mail.com', [email])
email.attach_file('file.jpg')
email.send()
```

I get an [Errno 111] Connection refused. What could be the source of this error? Are there any additional settings that I should be aware of when trying to send an email with an attachment in Django? Thanks a lot

[edit] I forgot to mention i am working on the development server provided by django

Answer (score 1):

most likely, Django can't connect to a mail server on localhost.  If you look [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#available-settings), look for EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD

Comment: What can I use instead of the default 'localhost' for the EMAIL_HOST ?

Comment: I would find the person that you go when there are email problems (they will be a sysadmin), and ask them for the connection info.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set the email for testing purposes in Django would be to set it to a gmail account with SMTP.

In settings.py just add this.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

For production you will need some sort of mail server installed on your server, or connect to a remote mail server.

Hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score -1):

Like Chris Curvey mentioned, you'll have to configure your mail settings as is described here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#available-settings

Which mail host to use depends on your connection. If you are at work, then there should be a system administrator who can tell you which information to use. If you're at your own home, then your ISP probably has a mail server that you're supposed to use.

If you have a functioning email client on your computer, then you should also be able to see the proper settings in "Outgoing Mail" or something to that effect.